# How to grade an interaction that a user had with a post with an AI based on big data?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, bigdata, recommender-system, ai

### **Context**

I'm creating a social network.

The thing is, **I don't want to order posts by likes, or something like that**, I'm using an AI (`lightfm` in `python`). This AI uses a hybrid recommendation system **based on ratings** that users have given to posts.

For this part, everything works, BUT for testing I was using **fake ratings** that I've manually entered the `database`.

**THE REAL QUESTION IS**, how do I get the rating that a user has given to a post **without asking him** and **only knowing his interactions** (liked, shared, commented, watch time, etc...)

Interaction example:

```json
{
    "average_watch_time": 2.4739250771067502,
    "follow_on_init": true,
    "id": 0,
    "interactions": [
        {
            "at": 1608370856,
            "id": 0,
            "type": "first_time"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370860,
            "id": 1,
            "type": "see_profile"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370861,
            "id": 2,
            "type": "come_back"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370869,
            "id": 3,
            "type": "unfollow"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370874,
            "id": 4,
            "type": "duo"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370880,
            "id": 5,
            "type": "come_back"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370890,
            "id": 6,
            "type": "double_click_like"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370892,
            "id": 7,
            "type": "see_profile"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370895,
            "id": 8,
            "type": "come_back"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370900,
            "id": 9,
            "type": "copy_link"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370907,
            "id": 10,
            "type": "duo"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370911,
            "id": 11,
            "type": "come_back"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370914,
            "id": 12,
            "type": "dislike"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370924,
            "id": 13,
            "type": "see_profile"
        },
        {
            "at": 1608370934,
            "id": 14,
            "type": "come_back"
        }
    ],
    "total_comments": 2814,
    "total_duos": 78,
    "total_likes": 45477,
    "total_shares": 1857,
    "total_views": 4853,
    "video_duration": 0.48587760432015425
}
```

## My solutions

### First one

At the beginning, I thought the best solution was to rate on `/20`. And for each type of interaction (liked, commented, etc…), give it a part of this final grade.
What I mean:

```
 Liked: /10;
 Commented: /2;
 Shared: /5;
 Followed: /3;
 Total: /20
```

The problems is that if I use this method it won't really work.
For example if **I share**, that means that **I liked** the post but if **I don't that doesn't necessarily mean that I didn't like it**. SO **THIS WILL REMOVE 5 points** because I didn't share.

### Second One

After that, I thought of making a **deep RL algorithm based on human preferences**.

The idea was that, I would create a client side website where a human can rate interactions.
For this I created another algorithm that would create **random interactions** and then simulate them on the client side

BUT AFTER I WAS BLOCKED. Why ?

Well, because I SIMPLY DIDN'T KNOW HOW TO DO. There is nothing on the internet ([except a really complex math document](http://papers.neurips.cc/paper/7017-deep-reinforcement-learning-from-human-preferences.pdf)) on deep RL.

### Third Solution

Finally, the last solution that I found was to give a weight to each type of interaction.

THE THING IS THAT, how could I give a weight to something that depends on other interactions (time between last interaction, repetition, video duration, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you will eventually have, after some time, those user ratings right? So, assuming that you will have some **labeled data** (i.e. user ratings together with the features you say) to train with, you can build a **multivariate regression model** (you can have a first look at [linear models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) to begin with).

This approach is similar to what you have said in your **option 3**, where you would like to find **ideal weights** for each of your "attributes" (the features you said like shares, interaction time, comments...), and that is what **you get by building that multivariate regression model**:

[image: linear regression]

where the predicted value is the user rating you want, each of the x1, x2... are your features and the w1, w2... the weights you want to find.
This is a quick model type to train and easy to follow; later on, you can go on with a neural network or something el se more sophisticated in case you need it.

Comment: I don't really understand if a multivariate regression model is used to predict the rating or to get weights

Comment: Both, but for your use case, you can directly use it for estimating the rating (asuming you have a training dataset labeled with already known ratings)